# Validator W3 Forbidden 403 error

Tags: api, http, w3c

The server rejects the connection validator.w3.org 403 error.

If the "new" computer to go to the address - that all the rules.

But once you open the link to API:http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yandex.ru%2F&verbose=0&ss=0&outline=0&output=soap12

IP-address blocks and even more impossible to go to the primary site

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask: checking the url `http://www.yandex.ru` results in a report pointing out lots of errors in the markup. This is not surprising when you take a look at the markup yourself, it appears somewhat "self tailored". What do you mean by "IP-address blocks and even more impossible to go to the primary site"? What IP address is blocked by whom or what and where? What site should it be impossible to "go to"?

Comment: W3-servers blocked my ip-address, after execute API-query. After block ip address, i unable to access to website validator.w3.org. I test that sitation from three computers from more networks and city (Moscow, Desnogorsk, Novosibirsk from Russia) and test from moscow hosting-providers on M10

Comment: Look again. You are most likely _not_ blocked in general. It is only that specific deep URL that is blocked, why ever. Have a try at http://validator.w3.org/, that probably will work for you too. It appears that either that deep URL you posted is block in general due to miss usage (high load), or the validation at their system indeed has an issue. But does that really matter? Why would you want to re-validate the same URL again and again?

Comment: Exactly - W3C blocked me general. After requested any url to api w3c, i unable to open main site page validator.w3.org (same error 403). I try to validate another url - not fix the problem. A few hours later - w3c open normally, but after execute api request (any url, not necessary yandex) - blocked me again. New moments: if remove "output=soap12" from get-arguments - works its fine. But that original api url generated by pear module for W3C API - https://pear.php.net/package/Services_W3C_HTMLValidator

Comment: OK, that is different for me. I am _not_ blocked for the general site, although I see the blocking message when using your posted link. So it looks like you got blocked, probably because you used that link to often which is considered miss usage by them. And we only receive the same message (which makes no sense here) when accessing exactly the same link. So a sloppy implementation on their side. Probably to prevent workaround the blockage by using proxies etc.

Comment: I pushed bugs to w3c and to pear package
https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=28860
https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=20566
In W3C API description says - soap12 experimental - https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html

Comment: W3C validator soap2 API protocol not supported any more.

Official answer from bug-tracker W3C:
> The output=soap12 option is obsolete and should not maintained and should no > longer be used or relied on.
> 
> We recommend instead using the current HTML checker with the out=json option.

Comment: OK, interesting and good to know. So thanks for reporting back in that issue here!